# Не выходит скомпилить dev-С++

Tags: winapi, c++

Запускаю на С++ вполне работающий проект и нажимаю f9 или скомпилить и выполнить, и пишет проект не откомпилирован, захожу в ту папку, а там работающее винапи приложение, меняю название на английское и все стало компилится, вопрос: в чем прикол?!

Comment: Можно уточнить - меняете название чего на английский?
И также - что за компилятор используете?

Comment: Название самого приложения, например: Project1 на Проект1.Компилятор дев с++ 4.9.9.2. Приложение после этого стало компилироваться.

Comment: А файлик Project1.exe, который был скомпилирован до этого случайно не запущен ?

+приведите полный лог ошибки компиляции

Comment: ЕМНИП в дев с++ компилятор mingw

Comment: Насколько помню, в деве компилятор gcc

Answer (score 1):

Вы изначально писали название приложения на русском? Если так, то, может быть, среда просто на поддерживает кириллицу.

Comment: она не поддерживает кириллицу, но файл скомпилирует, хотя и с примерно таким названием №;%:?Ш?Ш?:?:ГШНПШ?:.exe  
тут проблема в чем-то другом

Comment: ¦ЁюхъЄ1 это проект1

Answer (score 0):

Проблема видимо именно в среде. Может быть она написана для utf-8, а у Вас cp-1251  (или что-то в этом роде).

Компиляция (я так понял) проходит, а собранный .exe не вызывается. Скорее всего имя .exe файла и имя проекта (в каких-то таблицах среды) не совпадают.

А зачем Вам русские буковки в именах файлов ? От этого только головная боль у всех.